# Is Converting to Islam obligatory for Non Muslims?

Tags: sharia, conversion, judaism

The Jewish religion does not make it compulsory to convert to their religion , According to them the [Muslims can goto heaven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26328/2371) without converting to their faith , Hence, does Islam make it obligatory for non Muslims to convert to Islam?

Answer (score 3):

Assalamualaikum,

First of all, Allah says in Quran:

"Verily the only acceptable religion to Allah is Islam." [Quran 3:19]

So, based on this verse, it leaves no doubt that only if a person is muslim, then it will be accepted by him, otherwise he will be thrown to hellfire.

And logically, why converting to Islam makes sense?

It is due to the reason ,as Allah has said that no religion except Islam will be accepted by us, which proves that ALL other religions are rejected by Allah. If anyone follow any religion other than Islam, then surely he will go astray. Because All other religions are either corrupted, or man made.